# When to save and load app settings with sharedPreferences in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I wondered whether there is a best practice to save (or load) to (or from) sharedPreferences in Flutter. For example, consider the following simple app that saves the notification state (whether it is enabled or not) to sharedPreferences every time the button is pressed, and loads it in initState():

```
class HomaPageState extends State<HomePage> {
 bool notificationIsEnabled = true;
 
 Future<void> _loadNotificationState() async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
      notificationIsEnabled = pref.getBool('notificationIsEnabled') ?? true;
    });
  }

 Future<void> _saveNotificationState(bool notificationIsEnabled) async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((pref) {
      pref.setBool('notificationIsEnabled', notificationIsEnabled);
    });
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadNotificationState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Demo App',
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                notificationIsEnabled= !notificationIsEnabled;
              });
              await _saveNotificationState(notificationIsEnabled) ;
            },
            icon: Icon(notificationIsEnabled
                ? Icons.notifications_on
                : Icons.notifications_off),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: (...),
    );
  }
...
}
```

So how can I implement the best practice for saving and loading using shared preferences for this example?

For example, in Android, if I am not wrong, the best practice is to save it when the activity is killed and the onPause() method is called. Is there a similar way in Flutter?